# Macosx Deployment target firestore/firebase_core

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, deployment-target

Hello I get this error when I Run Flutter Code that contains firestore/firebase_core
i tried more than one deployment target but still, i get an error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
Building macOS application...
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:firebase_core
 - package:firebase_core_platform_interface
 - package:quiver
 - package:plugin_platform_interface
 - package:cloud_firestore
 - package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.7, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.9 to 11.0.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.6, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.9 to 11.0.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.7, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.9 to 11.0.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
** BUILD FAILED **

Exception: Build process failed
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because you’re trying to run your application with libraries that don’t support null safety. You can fix that by running your application with this command:

> flutter run --no-sound-null-safety

In case that you’re using an IDE, you need to change the running configurations, for example in VSCode will be:

> Code => Preferences => Settings => Search setting, type in "flutter test" => Dart: Flutter Test Additional Args, Add item => Add "--no-sound-null-safety

I suggest that you check [this](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety#testing-or-running-mixed-version-programs) link in order to understand how to understand this error better.